# EF Core missing Snapshot - Identity Server

Tags: c#, identityserver4, ef-core-2.0

I was tasked to update an IdentityServer Application to the newest version.

There are several differences between the ConfigurationDbContext and PersistedGrantDbContext and the current Database.

Usually i would create a migration and then update the Database, but in this project, there are no previous migrations or Database Snapshots.

So if i try to create a migration the whole Context is scripted and not only the changes.

How can i create a migration, that is only a diff between my current DB and the DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way should be to create initial migrations based on the context before upgrade, then upgrade dbContext(s) and create migrations for that.
Something like:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialConfigration -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/Configuration

dotnet ef migrations add InitialPersistedGrant -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrant
```

Then delete any code inside the `Up()` method in your Initial migrations code.
And finally

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Here you should have your initial migrations synced with your dbContext, and can upgrade the context and create the first real migration. Actually nothing special for IdSrv.